# Cross-compilation of rtl8192cu driver fails

Tags: makefile, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain, codesourcery

I 'm trying to cross-compile *rtl8192cu Driver* in my Linux x86 machine for an ARM machine. I downloaded driver from [Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false). Compilation guide refers editing Makefile as follows:

1. *Ensure that the $PATH variable includes the location of the toolchain that you will be using to cross-compile the module. Refer to the setup instructions for the location of this directory.*
2. *Set the KSRC environment variable is set to the location of your Beagleboard's kernel source (see cross-compilation environment setup instructions for this directory path).*
3. *Set the KVER environment variable to your beagleboard's kernel version.*

For this reson, I edited:

`KVER := 2.6.32` (2.6.32. is BB's kernel version)

`KSRC ?= /home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61` (compiled kernel sources, taken from BB, stored on `home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61` location)

**My question is:**

What do I have to edit on Makefile's field `CROSS_COMPILE:`? I edited the path `/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin` but
`make` fails with these errors:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin -C /home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61 M=/home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules
make[1]: /home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bingcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61'
  CC [M]  /home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: /home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bingcc: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

***INFO:*** Cross-toolchain on x86 machine is from CodeSourcery. I cross-compiled a helloworld.c for BB, by running `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c –o helloworld`, on `CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin` location.

Comment: R u compiling on x86 or beagle board?

Comment: If u cross-compiling on x86 make sure usr/src/linux-2.6.32.61 is cross-compiled for beagle board or atleast configured to beagle board so that makefile will get correct architecture.

Comment: I edited my question. I would be appreciated if you had a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bingcc: Command not found`

This error is due to you are not passing correct parameter

pass `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`

where ever it finds `{CROSS_COMPILE}gcc` {CROSS_COMPILE}ld ...etc

this will be replaced with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld`

Edit

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` -C /home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61 M=/home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules

If your cross-toolchain exported then try this

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` -C /home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61 M=/home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules

Comment: Cross-compiler problem solved. However, `make` fails again as it finds problem with BB's kernel sources: `make[1]: Entering directory /home/demetres/linux-2.6.32.61' CC [M]  /home/demetres/Downloads/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o /bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: Permission denied`. I think that it is due to permissions of linux-2.6.32.61 file.

Comment: check the permission of compiled kernel source